# Offset a LatLngBounds in a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I have a map that fills the screen, and a horizontal overlay of non-map content displayed in the bottom portion of the screen. I want to display a polyline on the map so that it as large as possible within the map view but *not hidden* below the overlaid content.

[image]

Below is what I am trying and it nearly works but gives different results depending on the zoom / position of the map's current view. I need something independent of the current view of the map.

```
// `map` is the leaflet map
// `polyline` is a leaflet polyline

function fitBounds (latLngBounds, offsetY) { // offsetY in pixels
  var zoom, southeast, southeastOffset, newBounds;

  if (offsetY) {
    zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latLngBounds);
    southeast = map.project(latLngBounds.getSouthEast(), zoom);
    southeastOffset = new L.Point(southeast.x, southeast.y + offsetY);
    newBounds = latLngBounds.extend(map.unproject(southeastOffset, zoom));
  }

  map.fitBounds(newBounds || latLngBounds);
}

var contentHeight = 350;
// this will be calculated and is the distance from the top of the
// overlaid content to the bottom of the map

fitBounds(polyline.getBounds(), contentHeight);
```

The `map.getBoundsZoom(latLngBounds)` and `project`/`unproject` seem to return different values when the map is panned or zoomed differently. I understood from the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html) that they'd be independent of the current map view.

Am I using the methods wrong, or is there a different strategy to achieve what I need? Thanks.

Comment: See the `leaflet-active-area` and `Leaflet.ControlledBounds`  plugins at the [leaflet plugins list](http://leafletjs.com/plugins#events), they implement strategies to decorate the calls to `fitBounds()` in a very similar way.

Comment: Thanks IvanSanchez. I've successfully got `leaflet-active-area` working on the problem, so that solves my issue. I am still interested why the original code did not work, if anyone can see it and wants to comment.

Answer (score 0):

`getBoundsZoom` is dependent on the current map view port size. Therefore if you test with different sizes (e.g. your map container fills the whole page width and you have varying browser window width, possibly because of the console), the results will be different.

If you are sure the map container size has not changed, and you can reproduce the problem on JSBin / Plunker / JSFiddle, then there might be a bug in Leaflet; feel free to report it in the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks. That may have been the issue.